# Unable to open VS2012 BI project after having to recreate Windows profile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012, ssdt-bi

I had to recreate my Windows user profile due to some technical problem that kept me from logging in. Now I'm trying to recover all my software, etc. I start VS2012 and opened the project I'm currently working on which is an SSDT/SSDT-BI project - database model and an SSIS project. I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning 1   Warning loading ADSMetricsETL.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node. Verify that the project was created by the same user. Project load will attempt to continue without the encrypted information.  ADSMetricsETL.dtproj    0   0
```

So I suspect there's a GUID or SID somewhere that identifies me as the owner of the SSIS packages and it's got my original profile's values stored identifying the "old me" as the owner. Is there any way to easily change ownership to my new profile?

Comment: Does the project eventually load?  This is just a warning, but I am wondering if it is successfully loading and you are just asking what's up with that warning?  Also, does dtproj.user exist?  If so, can you delete it and try again?

Comment: They are just warnings. The project builds. I edited all the connection managers and re-saved them to see if I could get rid of the warning but nope. I deleted the .dtproj.user file. That didn't change it either. Also, the packages all run correctly. Maybe I'm just being too picky?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a database project.  Could you change the protection level to DontSaveSensitive and see if that gets rid of the warning?  I have had similar issues come up when sharing packages and the encryption level is EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, which is the default

Comment: That got rid of the warning. Fortunately I don't have any sensitive data (all trusted connections) so it didn't break anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness sake I'll add my comments as an answer:
Change the protection level to DontSaveSensitive.  This warning usually comes up when sharing packages between different users since the default protection level is EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.

I'm glad that you do not have any sensitive information in the package -- it always best to use parameters or configurations.

Comment: I have one Oracle connection that I externalized to a Project Parameter. Our build/deploy automation reads a Properties file in JSON format to get the appropriate connection string for the environment (QA, Prod) and sets it via the Catalog SPs.  Thanks for the help.